# Ubuntu 16.04 ethernet not detected

Tags: networking, 16.04, dell, ethernet, xps

I have a Dell XPS 9360, with Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled, to which I connect a Thunderbolt 3.0 adapter. When I plugged in the Ethernet cable to the adapter, I was able to connect just fine. I went off to do something, the computer went to sleep, and when I woke it up from suspend, the ethernet was not found. Disconnection and reconnection hasn't worked. Clearly the hardware is OK but there's something odd happening.

Is there a way I can manually detect the ethernet (through terminal) similar to `sudo iwlist wlp58s0 scan` (which I run when the wireless networks are not showing up)? Or, ideally, how would I go about fixing this?

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
   logical name: wlp58s0
   version: 32
   serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-47-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.2.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:15154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:15154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:2136468 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:2136468 (2.1 MB)

wlp58s0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:d0:12:fb:9d  
        inet addr:192.168.2.111  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:de88:2ccc:4a4a/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:14083 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:13047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:7622828 (7.6 MB)  TX bytes:2421339 (2.4 MB)
```

Comment: Did you disconnect and reconnect the network cable to the adapter or the adapter to the computer?

Comment: Unplugging and reconnecting the adapter works, but since I'm using an external display, I don't want to have to unplug and replug every time my computer goes to sleep.  Any way I can simulate that in terminal?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, though there's hopefully a way to have it happen automatically. Something related to [this solution](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html) may work.